# Did Danny Pink fight in the 2001 War in Afghanistan?

Tags: doctor-who

In a flashback scene in *Dark Water*, we see Danny Pink fight in what looks like a Middle Eastern country.

Then, according to *Doctor Who Extra*, the narrator said that the crew made the set look like Afghanistan.

While it is not explicitly mentioned, is the war Danny fought in the 2001 War in Afghanistan?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Yes. [Danny Pink](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Danny_Pink) did indeed work and fight in Afghanistan. It was his military time there which soured him on war and he retired after accidentally killing a young boy.

> He was a sergeant and served five years in both the UK and Afghanistan, (TV: The Caretaker) where he performed a number of humanitarian tasks, such as building wells, alongside traditional military work. (TV: Listen)
>
> While on a mission in the Middle East, Danny accidentally shot and killed a young boy. (TV: Dark Water) He later referred to it as a "bad day" and the reason he left the army. (TV: Kill the Moon) **REF: TARDIS Data Core: [Danny Pink](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Danny_Pink)**

#### FROM the CARETAKER Script:

> [Courtyard]
>
> COURTNEY: Miss Oswald, Katie Sharps says I pulled her hair in Biology.
>
> CLARA: Courtney, you are big enough to look after yourself. Next class, jog on, I need to talk to Mister Pink.
>
> COURTNEY: Ozzie loves the Squaddie.
>
> CLARA: What was that?
>
> COURTNEY: Nothing.
>
> **ADRIAN: Of course, Danny Pink here is your man, Mister Smith. Five years' military experience, sergeant, here and Afghan, so electrics, boilers, if you need a hand, give him a shout.**

Comment: 5 years to Sergeant is awfully quick in the British Army.

Comment: @Gaius Maybe he didn't like his previous rank so made it up. ;)

Answer (score 3):

In the episode *The Caretaker*, we learn that Danny fought in Afghanistan. About eleven minutes in, we overhear a conversation between Bow Tie and the Doctor (posing as the interim caretaker, Mr. Smith):

> Of course, Danny Pink is your man, Mr. Smith. Five years military experience, sergeant, **here and Afghan.**

I think the “here and Afghan” comment means that Danny was deployed to Afghanistan, which is consistent with what we see elsewhere, and strongly suggests that it was the 2001 war in Afghanistan that he was fighting.

Answer (score -1):

I think it depends on your definition of the "2001 War".

The British Mission in Afghanistan ran from November 2001 until October 2014.[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_in_Afghanistan_%282001%E2%80%93present%29)

Danny's 5 years of service could come from any point in that 13 year window.

Comment: The answers above have stated that it was explicitly confirmed that the active portion of his tour was in Afghanistan.

Comment: All I was pointing out was that there was a wider range for this than just 2001

Comment: It's not a bad point, but if you wish to comment on the original question then a comment (or even an edit) would be the preferred option.